# Java non-blocking TLS PSK

Tags: java, ssl, vert.x, jsse

I'm working with a framework (Vertx 2) and need to implement a service that runs on top of TLS. Vertx 2 has support for TLS, but I cannot get it to use the necessary ciphers (among others):

- TLS_PSK_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

I also cannot use the Bouncy Castle lightweight API as it is stream-based and blocks (spawning threads etc. to deal with this is not acceptable as that will not scale). The same goes for JESSIE.

It must use AES & DES with pre-shared keys, but I've been unable to find a way to get this to work. Any solution which is non-blocking/async is workable.

Comment: it would be helpful to understand why you can't use the ciphers and what JDK is that

Comment: Assuming you mean JSSE (as tagged) that *does* provide nonblocking/async operation with "engine" mode on top of nonblocking NIO sockets. But that doesn't help you because JSSE *doesn't* do PSK, in any kind of I/O.

Comment: @OlegMikheev As dave_thompson said, JSSE doesn't implement any ciphers with PSK.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I meant both JSSE and the [JESSIE](http://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/www.gnu.org/jessie/index.html) library. Is there any way (without also re-implementing TLS) I can add PSK to the JSSE?

Comment: I never heard of JESSIE but from that link it appears to be pretty near dead. There's no API to directly add things to (Oracle) JSSE, only enable and disable what's already there. Java is mostly opensource (including JSSE) at http://openjdk.java.net/ and you could create your own copy and modify it, although I'm not sure the Java licensing would let you *distribute* it with the Oracle-version JRE/JDK (IANAL). FWIW, PSK is one of the simpler keyexchanges and once you understand the software structure it probably wouldn't be hard to add. ...

Comment: ... (updated) A possible alternative is that I just saw the latest (1.52) version www.BouncyCastle.org announced support for PSK and SRP in TLS. Their TLS uses their "lightweight" API (not the JCA-defined provider one) and I'm not even sure where to start although stackoverflow.com/questions/18065170/… might help. Or a possible alternative but probably more impact: you could do like Tomcat's "Native" option and wrap OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux or OSX, Conscrypt (https://conscrypt.org) might be an option. This is an OpenSSL/BoringSSL backed JCA Provider which will give you an SSLEngine impl which you can then use with Java NIO in non-blocking mode. For context, Conscrypt is the default provider of crypto and TLS/SSL primitives on Android.

To use it with TLS-PSK, you'll need to initialize a Conscrypt-provided SSLContext with an implementation of org.conscrypt.PSKKeyManager and then obtain an SSLEngine from that context. For documentation, see PSKKeyManager interface Javadoc or Javadoc of very similar Android framework class PskKeyManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/PskKeyManager.html).